# остановка прокрутки в событии

Tags: javascript

нужно что бы блок документа который имел прокрутку, при прокрутке до самого низа не вызывал событие прокрутки самой страницы (т.е. прокрутили до конца блока и стоп )
фидл - https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/3cmwv405/2/

догадки js

```
document.onwheel = function(e) {

if (e.target.tagName != "DIV") return;
var area = e.target;
    console.log(area);
var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

if (delta < 0 && area.scrollTop == 0) {
e.preventDefault();
}

if (delta > 0 && area.scrollHeight - area.clientHeight - area.scrollTop <= 1) {
e.preventDefault();
}
};
```

Comment: Вместо onwheel поставьте onscroll, тогда будет работать и для прокрутки стрелками, ползунком и вообще чем только можно. А onwheel только колесико мыши ловит

Comment: то же самое ( 
https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/3cmwv405/9/

Comment: то же самое что? У меня колесика мышки нет (как и самой мышки), так что я могу только строить догадки насчет проблем ваших догадок js. Вы ведь не потрудились описать вашу проблему. Так что я просто подметил один нюанс, а ответ вам кто-нибудь еще один напишет, у кого мышка под рукой

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var node = document.querySelector("#chating_list");
    function wheel(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        while (target != document) {
            if (target == node) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var delta = 0;
                if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
                else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;
                if (delta > 0) node.scrollTop -= 30;
                else node.scrollTop += 30
            }
            target = target.parentNode
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", wheel, false);
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", wheel, false)
});
```

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var node = document.querySelector("#chating_list");

  function wheel(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    while (target != document) {
      if (target == node) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var delta = 0;
        if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;
        if (delta > 0) node.scrollTop -= 30;
        else node.scrollTop += 30
      }
      target = target.parentNode
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("mousewheel", wheel, false);
  window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", wheel, false)
});
```

```css
    #chating_wrapper {
      padding-left: 30px;
      height: 2000px;
    }
    .chating_history {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .chating_block {
      width: 542px;
    }
    .chating_list {
      height: 175px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .chating_text {
      padding: 4px 0 4px 46px;
    }
    .manadger {
      width: 37px;
      height: 37px;
      background-image: url(../images/personal_cabinet/manadger.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      float: left;
      margin-top: -5px;
    }
    .aks {
      width: 37px;
      height: 37px;
      background-image: url(../images/personal_cabinet/aks.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      float: left;
      margin-top: -5px;
    }
    .data {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #a7a7a7;
      padding-left: 6px;
    }
    .text_color {
      color: #f38104;
    }
    .cating_field {
      width: 500px;
      height: 73px;
      padding: 14px;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-top: 18px;
      outline: none;
    }
    #btn_chating_history {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 85px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-top: 6px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #afafaf;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px #bcbcbc;
      outline: none;
    }
    ​
```

```html
<div id="chating_wrapper">

  <div class="chating_list" id="chating_list">

    <div class="chating_block">
      <div class="aks"></div>
      <p class="chating_text">Nesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ord <span class="data">25.12.15</span> 
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="chating_block">
      <div class="manadger"></div>
      <p class="chating_text text_color">Nesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ord <span class="data">12:40</span> 
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="chating_block">
      <div class="aks"></div>
      <p class="chating_text">Nesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ordNesdf sdw passw sdfsd ord <span class="data">12:50</span> 
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="chating_block">
      <div class="manadger"></div>
      <p class="chating_text">Nesdf sdw passw sdfsd ord <span class="data">25.12.15</span> 
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

остановкка скрола страницы над элементом